# DC Voltage drop multiplier confusion

Tags: voltage, power

I have half a meter of 18 AWG (1.02mm diameter) stranded copper wire and I am planning to run 12 volts with a maximum 6 amp load.

Determining the cross sectional `area = 0.51mm^2 * PI`, gives me ~`8.17e-07 meters`.

Determining the resistance `R = (1.72e-8 * 0.5 meters) / area`, gives ~`0.0105 Ohms` resistance for the half meter length.

My attempt to then determine voltage drop is `V = I * R`, `V = 6 * 0.0105`, giving a voltage drop of ~`0.063` (~`11.94V`)

Why then do many online calculators have a multiplier of `2` on this drop? (~`11.87V`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why then do many online calculators have a multiplier of 2 on this drop, ~11.87 V?

Because most circuits have a return wire.